# Can i re-enable the javascript alert()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

I reloaded my page
also in a whole new tab, but it would not show the alert(), because I accidentally
clicked do not show any of these popups, but I cant seem to do it again.

Please help

Comment: Try close the tab and re-open it.

Comment: If you read more carefully, I said I DID do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close that tab & open URL in new tab ... OR may be you are required to close the all Chrome windows ...

I know that is not permanent ..

Comment: I did do that just now; does not work.

Comment: You may require to close all instances of Chrome ...